# rails-3-jquery autocomplete not working with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

my autocomplete functionality using the gem https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete is not working. When I try to work with autocomplete in isolation (only one model) it works.

Here is my controller :-

```
autocomplete :location, :name
```

Model :-

```
belongs_to :location
```

View :-

```
 = fields_for @event.location do |location|

    = location.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_location_name_events_path, :placeholder => "Enter the name of the location"
```

routes :-

```
resources :events do
    get :autocomplete_location_name, :on => :collection
end
```

application.js.cofee

```
#= require autocomplete-rails
```

I am not able to debug properly either as to know what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try

Routes:

```
get 'events/autocomplete_location_name'
```

View:

```
fields_for :location do |location|
location.autocomplete_field :name, events_autocomplete_location_name, :placeholder => "Enter the name of the location"
```